# How can i turn the summernote requires?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, summernote

I have this and i want turn the summernote requires. I try to put a requires = requires, but doesnt work

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(at => at.Descricao, new { placeholder = "Descrição da 
Atração Turística", @class = "form-control m-b", id = "teste", rows = 10, 
data_tipo = "summernote" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(at => at.Descricao, new { placeholder = "Descrição da 
Atração Turística", @class = "form-control m-b", id = "teste", rows = 10, 
data_tipo = "summernote",@required  = "required" }
```